# JAVA remove line from file based on 2 inputs

Tags: java, swing

I am creating a program that stores books, book ID, and book Genre.
I am able to remove lines from a file based on an input but since that could lead to the user deleting a whole genre of books I would like it so that the user is required to enter both the book title and the book ID which should be in the same line delimited by # such as JamesandtheGiantPeach#01#Family. Is there a way for me to use a multiple input `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` so that it requires the user to enter both the book title and ID and then deletes the line of both of them are in a line?

I have looked around and I have found an answer using the scanner class but have no idea how to do it using `JOptionPane`. I know how to create a multi-input pane, however.

```
static void removeMovie() throws IOException {
 try {

  File inFile = new File("books.txt");

  if (!inFile.isFile()) {
   System.out.println("Parameter is not an existing file");
   return;
  }


  File tempFile = new File("books.txt" + "1");

  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inFile));
  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

  String line = null;

  String removeLine = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter line to remove");


  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   if (!line.trim().contains(removeLine)) {
    pw.println(line);
    pw.flush();
   }
  }

  pw.close();
  br.close();

  //Delete the original file
  if (!inFile.delete()) {
   System.out.println("Could not delete file");
   return;
  }


  if (!tempFile.renameTo(inFile)) {
   System.out.println("Could not rename file");
  }

 } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
 }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm confused. You know how to ask the user to enter a line to remove. So, just change the message, and ask him/her to enter a book title to remove. Then do it a second tipe and ask him/her to enter the book ID.

Comment: I know I can just do it twice, but I think it looks better if I am able to do it in 1 pane.

Comment: Then you need something otrher than a JOptionPane: a real JDialog, that you must design by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest use `JDialog`. Create class which extends `JDialog`. In this class you can create whatever you want. JDialog has constructor with JFrame and JDialog, so you can put your frame as parent, and after confirm delete fire method from parent to delete book from file

Comment: I use `JOptionPane` only to show message to inform user about something